# Função numero na Lista

Tags: c

Pessoal tenho essa função `tem_numero_na_lista` acontece que ela está imprimindo na tela apenas o último valor que inseri na lista.
O efeito que desejo é imprimir se tem ou não números dentro da lista.
Veja:

```
tipo_lista * tem_numero_na_lista (tipo_lista * p, int valor)
{
while (p != NULL)
{
    if (p -> info == valor)
    {
        printf("Tem %d numero(s) na Lista\n", p->info);
        return true;
    }
p = p -> prox;
}
printf("Não tem numero na Lista!\n");
return false;
}

int main() {
tipo_lista * recebida = inicializaLista();

int valor;    //uso esse?

bool valor3;  //uso esse?
case 9:
        tem_numero_na_lista(recebida, valor);
        system("pause");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Você passa um número para a função e ela diz se ele está na lista ou não. Aqui está funcionando normal a função. Talvez não esteja testando direito.

Comment: Eu adicionei o meu teste feito na main, talvez eu não estou sabendo testar mesmo.

Comment: Aqui ele retorna o último valor que digitei, entendeu? Insiro valor 2, depois valor 8, escolho opção 9 a saída correta é 2, 2 números, e não 8. é isso que ocorre, está imprimindo o último valor que digitei '8'.

Comment: Mas a função que você criou verifica se um valor está na lista; não tem nada a ver com a quantidade total de valores. Foi você mesmo que fez esses códigos?

Comment: Essa função eu passo o valor e verifico se tem na lista, é isso.